# Search html for a hardcoded JavaScript variable with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a HTML-Parser.
I managed extracting contents of several html-tags with simplehtmldom.

The last one I'm trying to find out is the most efficient way to get a hardcoded JavaScript variable.

The following snippet occurs in every page I want to analyse:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><!--
  var jobPopup145169852;
  var MONS_LOG_VARS = { //LoggingVars
  JobID : 145169852, 
  ApplyType : 0, 
  PopUpMessage: 'Ihr Popup-Blocker verhindert die korrekte Ausführung dieser Seite.', 
  EE: 'EAAQrXuZmYIUF5avSTEZs5tdZQ--', 
  ApplyOnlineUrl: '', 
  TrackingCompany: 'Company Name', 
  TrackingLogo: '', 
  JobWinPopup : jobPopup145169852, 
  YTA : 0, 
  LogUrl :'http://stellenanzeige.monster.de/log.ashx?PositionAdID=145169852&folderid=182198220&tracking=EAAQ.8ifh6a7iJ7indez5y2mEw--&logtype='
  }
//--></script>
```

Now I want to look for the value in the variable "TrackingCompany".
In this example, `Company Name`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post you code please?

Comment: There is none. Simplehtmldom just analyses tags so I thought it is impossible to get it done. So actually I'm looking for a solution without simplehtmldom.

Comment: Ahhh well you should try something first. :) is that code is same on every page?

Comment: so simplehtmldom returns you the above script as a string? then just analize the string with normal string functions - find "TrackingCompany" and use substring to get your value

Comment: Jep, every page contains that javaScript-Snippet in <head> and also the Variable TrackingCompany. One of my thoughts was to get the content of the <head> Tag and then substring it. But: the head section is very huge. Is this the only possibility?

Comment: @ChristianBusch Please try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx for this.

Regex: `/TrackingCompany: \'([a-zA-Z\s]+)\'/`

Explanation and working demo of this RegEx: https://www.regex101.com/r/vV3aE5/1

PS. This RegEx assumes that your company name has alphabets and spaces only. Just in case if you want to include numbers in it too, use: `/TrackingCompany: \'([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\'/`. If you have special characters too, append it inside the square brackets in the RegEx.

---

**Try this following working PHP code.** `// comments inline`

```
// take all of the file contents into a string $subject
$subject = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><!--
  var jobPopup145169852;
  var MONS_LOG_VARS = { //LoggingVars
  JobID : 145169852, 
  ApplyType : 0, 
  PopUpMessage: 'Ihr Popup-Blocker verhindert die korrekte AusfÃ¼hrung dieser Seite.', 
  EE: 'EAAQrXuZmYIUF5avSTEZs5tdZQ--', 
  ApplyOnlineUrl: '', 
  TrackingCompany: 'Company Name', 
  TrackingLogo: '', 
  JobWinPopup : jobPopup145169852, 
  YTA : 0, 
  LogUrl :'http://stellenanzeige.monster.de/log.ashx?PositionAdID=145169852&folderid=182198220&tracking=EAAQ.8ifh6a7iJ7indez5y2mEw--&logtype='
  }
//--></script>
EOT;

// initialize the RegEx pattern
$pattern = '/TrackingCompany: \'([a-zA-Z\s]+)\'/';

// execute the RegEx over the string
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

// check the matched contents
echo $matches[1][0];
```

You can try and execute this code in http://writecodeonline.com/php/ to check it quickly.

---

Read up: [preg_match manual | PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @ChristianBusch Things like parsing are pretty easy with RegEx. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: I think it is time to wrap my head around regEx expressions. Is this the most efficient and fastest way to do this?

Comment: @ChristianBusch For such use case, a RegEx is most efficient and fastest.